# Why are sine and cosine vectors?

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces

I understand that sine and cosine functions are vectors, and I understand that what defines a vector is how it transforms under change of basis. Am I correct in understanding that means that for some angle $\alpha$ in the $(x,y)$ coordinate system and some $\alpha'$ in the rotated coordinate system $(x',y')$ $$\sin(\alpha')=\frac{\mathrm{d}\alpha}{\mathrm{d}\alpha'}\sin(\alpha)?$$

I've tried working with this definition for the transformation, which I've been led to believe is correct, but I can't seem to show that it holds. Is this even a correct starting point? If not, what is?

Comment: Isn't the definition of vector "element of a vector space"? In that case, sine and cosine are vectors because there are vector spaces containing them, for example the set of all real functions with standard function addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: This makes very little sense to me, and so from the very beginning. Transformations are not what *define* vectors. Sine and cosine functions can be considered as vectors but I doubt that this is really related with what you can possibly be trying to do when you write the subsequent equation.

Comment: You should start by defining the framework in which you want to work - the real plane, with two coordinate systems. Then, explain how $\alpha$ and $\alpha '$ are really related (as a change of $x$-$y$ coordinates does not induce naturally a change in angles. Otherwise $\frac {d\alpha '}{d\alpha}$ makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

The word "vector" means slightly different things in various contexts. In linear algebra, a *vector space* is a structure satisfying a certain list of axioms, and a "vector" is just an element of whatever vector space you're talking about.

In that sense $\sin$  and $\cos$ are vectors; they're elements of for example $C(\Bbb R)$, the space of all continuous functions on the line. *But* this use of the word "vector" has more or less nothing to do with the thing you understand about how a "vector" is defined by how it changes under coordinate transformations.

That second sense of the word comes up in differential geometry, where for example it distinguishes vectors from "co-vectors".

I may be oversimplifying, but I believe that the word is being used in two different ways in "$\sin$ is a vector" and "what defines a vector is how it transforms under change of basis".

Comment: Someone should explain what the problem is...